# Relationship between workflow and capacity or shrinking log files?

Tags: workflow

This is on a newly configured Sharepoint 2019 on-premise site.

We started to experience an issue with both the SharePoint_config_log and the WSS_Content_log (content database) log files being full. To resolve this I shrunk the log files. (set database Recovery Mode to Simple, shrunk the log, switch Recovery Mode back to Full).

We have several lists that have workflow that is triggered when an an item is changed. At the same time as experiencing the log capacity issue and shrinking the logs we've been seeing workflows kicking off for items that were not recently updated.

Is there a relationship between recovery mode, logs and workflow triggering?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The growth of the logs may be related to the wf triggering. Maybe there is some badly designed loop that makes too many updates on the file resulting in multiple minor versions created?

Other option is that your log files are too small vs the size of the DB. In General shrinking should be avoided unless there was a lot of content deletions.

Your maintenance plan should handle the log situation.

Please look at those best practices:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/sharepoint-database-maintenance-recommendations/ba-p/323370

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/best-practices-for-sql-server-in-a-sharepoint-server-farm?redirectedfrom=MSDN